# Use native 64bit Toolset in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I have the problem that Visual Studio 2013 uses the 32bit cl.exe when building for 64bit Targets (VC\bin\x86_amd64) - it produces 64bit Code but runs with max. 4GB of Memory (visible via TaskManager -> *32 next to cl.exe).

Since I get the Error C1060 "compiler is out of heap space", I would really like to make use of the native 64bit Toolchain.

Its located alongside the Cross-Toolchain in VC\bin\amd64, but how can I configure Visual Studio to use it?

Additionally, I use CMake to generate my project. Is there a CMake option to select this Toolchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2013 defaults to using the 'cross-compiler' which is the 32-bit EXE version of the x64 compiler. You can set an environment variable "set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64" before you start up the VS IDE to get it to use the 64-bit native EXE version of the x64 compiler.

Note that in VS 2012 this was "set _ISNATIVEENVIRONMENT=true"